# PHP - secure MySQL Login with certificate

Tags: php, mysql, ssl-certificate

I have got a PHP script, which have to login to a MySQL-Database via PDO:

```
new PDO("mysql:host=<IP>;dbname=<database>;charset=utf8", "<user>", "<password>")
```

Is it possible to secure the login to the MySQL-Database with a SSL-Certificate, to use the key-file as password?

Comment: As of PHP 5.3.7 PDO_MySQL supports `PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CERT` and related connection attributes. I'd try with that. http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php